# Android Studio keeps generating .android folder in wrong location on computer running OneDrive

Tags: java, android, windows, directory, onedrive

**Problem :**
Android Studio keeps making .andoid cache folder in wrong direction.

**Background :**
I am using Windows 8.1 pro X64 and OneDrive.
I move some of my Windows Special folders like Desktop folder to my OneDrive folder to keep it synced between my computers. I usually put currently active work files on Desktop, and keeping it in sync greatly helps me in keeping my workplaces stay synced up with the latest files.
The problem arose when I started learning Android development lately. I installed the Android Studio on my PC, and the software started making folders where it is not supposed to. I did manage to tweak the settings and solved most of the problems, but there is one folder that doesn't accept the change.

My desktop folder is located in `C:\Users\[MyName]\OneDrive\UserFolder\Desktop`, and I configured that all android related folders to be created in `C:\Users\[MyName]\Applications\Android`. However, when I run the Android Studio, it keeps creating a new folder, `.android\cache` in `UserFolder`.

This is strange because other folders are created where they should be. After a process of elimination, I found out that this misbehaving folder seems to be in fact following the location of the `Desktop` folder and is being created in it's parent folder. I tried moving the `Desktop` folder around a bit, and every time I tried moving it the folder followed to the new location. I tried tweaking the environment variables and `idea.properties` file and nothing worked for this specific file. I suspect this is related with with JDK 7.0's `{user.home}` variable, because when I tried using `{user.home}` variable in `idea.properties` to change the folder paths, all Android Studio files were created in the same location where this problematic folder is being created(I ended up writing the actual folder path in the `idea.properties` file instead of using a variable).

`cache` folder doesn't seem to be that large in size and I am using an unlimited data plan so traffic is not an issue to me, but since `.android` is not a valid Windows file system name, it may cause some trouble with the sync engine, and that's why I'm so concerned with this issue.

This may be one of those "Extreme Usage Scenarios" in terms of UX or development point of view, but I think maybe I could find peers sharing the same problem or get some ideas on how to solve this issue here.

Thanks.

**Addition :**
I changed ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable to `C:\Users\[MyName]\Applications\Android\.android` from `C:\Users\[MyName]`
Now it is creating the folder in the designated location instead of `UserFolder`, and the problem is fixed for me.
But why did it follow the `Desktop` folder into the OneDrive folder in the first place? It's not like that the environment variable was pointing to the `UserFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I moved the Desktop folder back to the default location (I set it into the OneDrive Folder before) and now it works. Thank you for mentioning that the Desktop folder is the location where AndroidStudio starts to load (with relative path) the config and system folder.